# dynamic value when resize

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I would like to know how I can do that the value of customPadding will dynamically take value from the variable "widthToPadding" when it is resize

```
let windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    containerWidth = $('.container').width(),
    widthToPadding = ((windowWidth - containerWidth) - 30 ) / 2;


$('.gallery-realization').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrows: false,
    centerPadding: widthToPadding + 'px',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
} 


 <div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>

 var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
 containerWidth = $('.container').width(),
 widthToPadding = ((windowWidth - containerWidth) - 30 ) / 2;

var pxc=widthToPadding+"px";

console.log(pxc);


$(".single-item").slick({
    dots: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrows: false,
    centerPadding:pxc,
});
```

Comment: After update code don't work on resize. I would like to update centerPadding in resize

Comment: can you comment  fiddle link